# WPF C# Отображение объектов на Canvas (2d Map)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm

Задача: Создать приложение "Создание карт исследований месторождений".
1) Есть панель, на панели расположены кнопки с изображением которое мы хотим отобразить на экране, далее его параметры, и его координаты.
2) Размещаем изображения на экране нажав на кнопку и перетащив на экран (это у нас Toggle Button)
3) Соединяем размещенные изображения стрелками
Вот какой должен быть конечный вариант "Примерно")):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел более менее достойный пример, переделал по максимуму под свои задачи, добавил объекты, убрал лишнее и т.д.

Вопросы:
1) Могу добавлять изображения на Canvas не более одного, не пойму в чем проблема, приложение написано по MVVM. При нажатии на кнопку, выделяются обе кнопки, то тащит объект тот который был последним положен на canvas.
2) Все формируется в Node/NodesEditor.xaml, в canvas, в canvas даю ссылки на изображения, панель лежит отдельно Menu/ButtonsPanel.xaml кнопки Toggle Button берут те же изображения для вида, так же Toggle Button принимает ссылку из класса Node/MainViewModel.cs от метода CreatingNewNode.
3) Где лежит проблема не пойму, один метод не может через Binding (Menu/ButtonsPanel.xaml) использоваться на несколько кнопок? Перестроить логику canvas (Node/NodesEditor.xaml)? Переделать метод CreatingNewNode (Node/MainViewModel.cs)?

Ссылка на гитхаб: https://github.com/talasbaev/LabApp.git

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET https://community.esri.com/community/developers/
Этот фреймворк специально разработан для работы с картами